if there is a better way to round a floating number using expl3?
% here is some code.  not sure if it is a right way to define a new command . But it work as expected.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\ro}[2][2]{\fp_eval:n { round ( #2 , #1 )}}  
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ro{3.1415926}

\ro[4]{3.1415926}


\end{document}


I'm not sure how you are defining 'better' here - could you elaborate on what you think is wrong?

yes, no problem. You could also do \newcommand{\ro}[2][2]{\fpeval{round(#2,#1)}}   without the ExplSyntax commands.

this requires load fp package addionally.

Not with a modern kernel, then \fpeval is in the kernel as well, see sources2e.pdf

I'd use \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\ro{O{2} m}{\fpeval{round(#2, #1)}}

Since the FPU of expl3 is expandable, and I'd assume you might want to further use the results of this function, I'd define the command expandable as well.
Macros defined with \newcommand are only expandable if they don't use optional arguments. Since you want the precision to be an optional argument I'd use \NewExpandableDocumentCommand instead for this. Also, move definitions of new commands into the preamble, not the document body. Otherwise your code looks fine (though as @UlrikeFischer mentioned you don't need \ExplSyntaxOn).
\documentclass{article}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ro}{O{2} m}{\fpeval{round(#2, #1)}}

\begin{document}

\ro{3.1415926}

\ro[4]{3.1415926}


\end{document}


Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.
